# Running Total In Query Using Debit & Credit Transactions

Tags: ms-access

Running Total in Query:  I am attempting to create a query that has running totals using Debits & Credits.  I can get this working in a Report but for this example i need a query and am not coming up with the correct formula here. The formula I am using for Running Balance is:
RunningBalance: Nz([Credit],0)-Nz([Debit],0)

[ScreenShot of Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysyf1.png)

I have tried variations using Dsum and Sum but cannot seem to get any iterations of this formula to work.    The formuala I'm using in the example is
RunningBalance: Nz([Credit],0)-Nz([Debit],0)

Comment: Edit question to post query as formatted SQL code and data as formatted text table, not images. Running totals in Access query is not simple.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running Total in Access Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533039/running-total-in-access-query)

Answer (score 0):

I worked up a generic answer:  Assuming You have a table with columns ID, A,B,C, D like:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         ID         |         A          |         B          |         C          |         D          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 | a                  | b                  | c                  |                  1 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 | a                  | b                  | c                  |                  2 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  3 | a                  | b                  | c                  |                  3 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  4 | a                  | b                  | c                  |                  4 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  5 | a                  | b                  | c                  |                  5 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Assuming you want a running sum of Column D as ID increases like :

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         ID         |         A          |         B          |         C          |    RunningTotal    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  1 | a                  | b                  | c                  |                  1 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 | a                  | b                  | c                  |                  3 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  3 | a                  | b                  | c                  |                  6 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  4 | a                  | b                  | c                  |                 10 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  5 | a                  | b                  | c                  |                 15 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then cut and paste the following sql into the sql pane.  (after cutting and pasting Table1 into a text file and then importing table1 into access.)

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.A, Table1.B, Table1.C, (SELECT SUM(t.D) FROM Table1 as t WHERE Table1.ID>= t.ID) AS RunningTotal
FROM Table1
ORDER BY Table1.ID;
```

After Saving and switching to the Design Pane you will see something similar to :

[image]

When you run the query you will get the desired results.

RunningTotal is calculated using a subquery as a column.  In the design view RunningTotal shows as a calculated field.  The basic idea is to create a duplicate of the original table (here t) and decide on how you are ordering the RunningTotal( here by ID ascending).  From there you can grab the columns from Table1 or t and then calculate RunningTotal from the unused table.

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for unfortunately.  My data set has debits and credits in separate columns and i need to get a running balance per account based on debit and credit entries. The columns look like:

Comment: transaction_id       transaction_date     account_number     debit     credit    run_bal

Comment: The idea is to replace D with a calculated field (Debit + Credit) and if Transaction is a date with time you c\an use it as ID directly or add a TransactionID