# Running Total based on three criteria, one column with date function the other two with short text

Tags: ms-access

I have a Query with

- Date Column.
- Item Column.
- Color Column.(each item has different color)
- Total In Column.
- Total Out Column.
- Balance Column is (Total In-Total Out)

I am looking to get the sum of balance for each item on daily basis After new date entry.
I can get the Sum of Balance for the first date correctly ,moving to the next day the Balance becomes a negative.

Currently am creating a new query from this query to get the sum of Balance

```sql
SELECT [BALANCE QUERY FINAL].Date, [BALANCE QUERY FINAL].Item, [BALANCE QUERY FINAL].Color, Sum([BALANCE QUERY FINAL].BAL) AS BALANCE
FROM [BALANCE QUERY FINAL]
GROUP BY [BALANCE QUERY FINAL].Date, [BALANCE QUERY FINAL].Item, [BALANCE QUERY FINAL].Color;
```

[This is my query.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLMHj.png)

I will appreciate with any assistance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running total query in access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936340/running-total-query-in-access)

Comment: Build a report and use its Sorting & Grouping features and RunningSum property of textbox

Comment: No,Assist on exactly how the running total formula should be??

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/summing-in-reports-ad4e310d-64e9-4699-8d33-b8ae9639fbf4#bmrunningsum